# How to fix dimension problem in Python shape of x and y differ

Tags: python

My code runs and returns the value of `K` as expected but the graph does not display `w`, due to an issue with dimensions. I'd be thankful for any help.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

k = np.linspace(0,0.1,1000)
h = 50
g = 9.81
w = 0.5*(np.ones(len(k)))

w = np.sqrt((g*k)*np.tanh(h*k))

k = max(k[w<=0.5])
print("The wave number, k = %.4f" % k)

pl.figure()
pl.plot(k, w)
pl.show()
```

However, plotting returns the following error:

> x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (1000,)

Comment: I think you mean `k` and `w` not `x` and `y`.. right??

Comment: well you define `k` as `max(k[w<=0.5])`, which is a scalar. Not sure what you are expecting

Comment: yes i mean k and w, im expecting to get a curve where k at the point when w <= 0.5 would be displayed on the curve

Comment: @Daniel then you might want to include also this after you plot: `pl.plot(kmax,w[k==kmax],'.',color='r')`

Comment: Thanks @Gio, this helps a lot

Comment: Remember to self answer the question, explain the solution , and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

k = np.linspace(0,0.1,1000)
h = 50
g = 9.81
w = 0.5*(np.ones(len(k)))

w = np.sqrt((g*k)*np.tanh(h*k))

kmax = max(k[w<=0.5])
print("The wave number, k = %.4f" % kmax)

pl.figure()
pl.plot(k, w)
pl.show()
```

[image: output]

OP also mentioned in a comment that he would like to mark the point kmax on the plot.
This can be done as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

k = np.linspace(0,0.1,1000)
h = 50
g = 9.81
w = 0.5*(np.ones(len(k)))

w = np.sqrt((g*k)*np.tanh(h*k))

kmax = max(k[w<=0.5])
print("The wave number, k = %.4f" % kmax)

pl.figure()
pl.plot(k, w)
pl.plot(kmax,w[k==kmax],'.',color='r')
pl.show()
```

[image: output2]